# What are some of the challenging problems to adapt to map reduce framework?

Tags: java, python, hadoop, mapreduce

I have developed around 20 jobs on map reduce including the pagerank algorithm. I never found any challenging problems to adapt to mapreduce framework online. I would like to improve my skills. Is there such a guide?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Data intensive programming task. Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353582/computational-linguistics-project-idea-using-hadoop-mapreduce) already posted at StackOverflow.  I thought of suggesting [this project](http://code.google.com/p/wikipedia-map-reduce/) because corpus from wikipedia is easily available, but as you can see it is already in progress.

Run a squid reverse proxy and collect the logs of those over a period of time. Now use those logs and try to derive meaningful interpretation of those and store them in suitable database for querying. This could be good project to do.